# Why my silent installation of SQL express 2019 getting error?

Tags: sql, installation, silent-installer

I Want Silent installation of SQL Express 2019 with the Advanced Installer program. I using Below Parameter for this, But only the extraction part is worked and SQL Express not installed. it seems is getting error, But no error show. also I want use of Default parameter So I can use "." as Local Host in any system. how can I Solve it?

```
/x:C:\ExtractionFolder /qs /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
```

update:
Also I found if I replace /qs with /INDICATEPROGRESS I can see the errors and step by step GUI Setup. I do it and now The default values I put in the command line are correctly placed and there are no errors. However I Still want use the "qs". It was written in document that I read, in this way the GUI is completely hidden from the user's view. As a result, it no longer faces installation complications; But in this case, silent installation does not work. How do I fix this? –

Comment: Check the Windows event logs.

Comment: i check it but there is no log for silent install SQL express. So I think the line my mention above not working and not run setup, But I do not know why.

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver16 - **there is a log file** for silent-logs:, it's at `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log `

Comment: I checked it again. there is no log on that address. Also I found if I replace /qs with /INDICATEPROGRESS I can see the errors and step by step GUI Setup. I do it and now The default values I put in the command line are correctly placed and there are no errors. However I Still want use the "qs". It was written in document that I read, in this way the GUI is completely hidden from the user's view. As a result, it no longer faces installation complications; But in this case, silent installation does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section